# Gimp crashed on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gimp

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 Gimp crashes quite often.

Most of the time it happens if I use ctrl-a ctrl-c.

Is there anything I can do to solve this?

I am using this version: `GNU Image Manipulation Program Version 2.10.20`

I will use Krita now, but I am used to Gimp and too lazy to learn a new app.

Comment: This version came not installed with Ubuntu 20.04. It can happen that unsupported software is unstable on your system. Edit your question and indicate how you installed 2.10 on your system. Eventually also add detail on how you experience the crash: does it immediately terminate, or does if freeze...?

Comment: @vanadium I just installed it. Wait ... via snap. Don't ask me why there are two ways to install gimp on ubuntu. Which one is the right way to install Gimp?

Comment: @vanadium thank you for asking. I installed it via `apt` now - maybe this is stable (version 2.10.18)

Comment: hmm, also Snap is officially supported, so also the snap version, which indeed will be the more recent, should in principle be OK. Some snap packages, however, prove to be flaky - some even do not start.

Answer (score 1):

here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2452475&p=13994804#post13994804 I have found a solution that works for me. After closing qlipper Gimp works fine again.

Comment: I use the clipboard manager copyQ. I use copyQ much more than I use gimp. Removing it is not a solution for me.

Comment: I tested copyQ and with that application I don't have the copy-and-paste problem.